# Where am I to most likely find the last 16 coins in Live Freemium or Die?

Tags: dlc-quest

I found all DLCs but am now stuck at 184 coins, while the shopkeeper's door requires 200 coins to pass. Most likely I missed one hidden cave with 16 coins, though of course I could also have missed multiple locations. I'm pretty sure I did a thorough search though and my patience for revisiting each and every location a third time starts to fade... So, where did I most likely miss 16 coins in one place? Or if that is not easily answerable, where is a map (or list) of all possible coin locations?

Comment: Does this need 3 separate tags for the same thing, two of which you've created for this question?

Comment: @Robotnik No, not really - I thought it's a separate DLC but it's "just" the second quest

Comment: Fair enough, I think separate dlc is fine, just not two tags for the same thing. If anything, you could probably make them synonyms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were inside the wall-covered region shown here:

[image]

Source: http://steamcommunity.com/app/230050/discussions/0/828934913115930720/#c828934913238660386